# How to check if a Facebook page post shared by a certain user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I need a way to learn if a user had shared a post (link, video, photo etc.) which is published by a Facebook page. I have the object_id and link of the post, and user_id of the user considered. Is there a Graph API or FQL (or something else) solution to ask Facebook if the user re-shared the post or not? Or is it possible to get a list people who shared the post? So, I can extract my answer from this list.

Note that I know it is possible to find the answer by crawling the user's wall feed. But it is time consuming and I need a more efficient way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: will not work. directly, but you can as you say get all stream posts of given user (as long as you have the permission) by FQL, with the filter_type 'other' the amount of data to crawl should be acceptable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get a list of all the shares of a facebook post](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/11491908/get-a-list-of-all-the-shares-of-a-facebook-post)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following FQL to get the data you're looking for.

```
SELECT via_id, created_time, owner_comment
FROM link
WHERE owner = me()
```

You can then compare via_id against the posts author (page ID) to determine if this share came from the page in question.

Unfortunately, there seems to be a bug with the data return where some of the via_ids come back as 0.  There is a ticket in with Facebook which, at the time of this post, has been open for three weeks at medium priority.  I have no idea if this issue is specific to my app or affects everyone, but that's the query to get what you want.